# .Net Entity Framework Code First Model Design

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model, code-first

I have multiple parent tables with a one-to-many relationship to a single child table.  Obviously the three public virtuals (Quote, PurchaseOrder, Invoice) will not work in my example below.  What is the correct pattern to do this?  Maybe an inheritance pattern with a discriminator? Thanks In Advance!

```
public class UserActivityLog
{
    public int UserActivityLogId { get; set; }

    public int ParentTableEnum { get; set; }  //1-Quote, 2-PurchaseOrder, 3-Invoice

    public int ParentProcessId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentProcessId")]
    public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentProcessId")]
    public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentProcessId")]
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public int QuoteId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserActivityLog> UserActivityLogs { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserActivityLog> UserActivityLogs { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserActivityLog> UserActivityLogs { get; set; }
}
```

Problem Example:

```
UserActivityLog
UserActivityLogId ParentTableEnum ParentProcessId
1                 1               1
2                 2               1
3                 3               1

Quote
QuoteId
1

PurchaseOrder
PurchaseOrderId
1

Invoice
InvoiceId
1
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? Can you show me the migration for UserActivityLog table?

Comment: The migration went through without error amazingly, but I see lots of potential problems.  For example, if one of the parent records are deleted how would EF know how to correctly handle the cascading delete with the example I just added above?  The ParentTableEnum field means nothing to EF at this point.

Comment: How would you like to do this in SQL? Fundamentally EF can't do anything which SQL does not allow. You could handle orphan records in code. Whenever you delete from the parent table, delete from the child as well. Or you can have 3 mapping tables, for each of your parent child relationship. That's ways it can cascade. But IMHO that's a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Since you mentioned inheritance, you could achieve this by all of the three approaches. But be sure to read the pros and cons. Here is a good start:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: "How would you like to do this in SQL?"  That's an inherent question of my question.

Comment: Every example of inheritance is either one-to-one, one-to-many, or one-to-many-or-any.  Are you saying to me that you have first hand knowledge that inheritance also works for many-to-one?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say every example of inheritance that I have seen.